# YouTube OAuth login with hard coded user name and password

Tags: oauth, youtube, hardcoded

I am developing an iPhone application. This app supports an feature where user can upload a video to YouTube account which is shared by all the app users.

When app receives upload request, it internally logs-in to the common YouTube account and uploads the video.

As per my understanding OAuth is the secure way to log-in to any site compared to non-Oauth. Since only app knows the user-name and password, login dialog (web-view with user-name and password fields) should not be prompted to the user.

Is there any mechanism available in GData framework that supports OAuth authentication without prompting the user for user-name and password (i.e OAuth authentication with hard-coded user name and password)?

EDIT: Since my app is the owner of common YouTube account, can I user 'Client Login' mechanism for login? Is OAuth is preferred for hiding app user's account credentials from the app?

Comment: "ince only app knows the user-name and password" -- app **doesn't know** anything but pair of tokens, they don't have direct connection to login and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way an app can sign in with the account username and password is via ClientLogin. ClientLogin support is built into the [GData library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).

Signing in via OAuth 2 always requires that the user provide the credentials directly to the server via a webview; the application is not involved with signing in.

Note that ClientLogin sign-in can sometimes face a server challenge, such as when the user must solve a captcha, so it's not guaranteed to be reliable.

Putting the account name and password into an application may not be secure, as users can disassemble an application to obtain the credentials.

A more reliable approach would be for your installed application to send the files to your server, and your server then uploads them to YouTube.